# Will a key-pair setup between two digital ocean droplets (Jenkins and App) still work after recreating from snapshots?

Tags: jenkins, digital-ocean, snapshot, key-pair

I have two digital ocean droplets - one set up for Jenkins and the other for my Node.js app and I have an ssh key-pair setup between them so Jenkins can deploy to the app server.

My question is if I take regular snapshots of these machines and need to restore them from the snapshot to new droplets, will I have to regenerate the key pair to continue using Jenkins to deploy, or will the original key pair work as they're both clones of the old machines?

If they won't work, is there an alternative way to spin up a new droplet from the snapshot without this need to reconfigure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing some more experimentation by temporarily switching the servers off and restoring snapshots from my backups - **the key-value pairs *do not* need to be regenerated when restoring from backups**, they are just pairs and neither side is reliant on the underlying machine.

It turns out I was statically referencing the old IP address in two locations in my code which is why the deployment was failing - I had only updated one. I've now gotten rid of those magic numbers and I just need to restart some processes when restoring from backup and my CI/CD pipeline is back online.

I hope this info helps somebody else!